# Can namespace be variable

Tags: tcl

namespace must be plain text, it cannot be meta elements such as variable or nesting script. E.g. there is no way you can do the following:

```
set ns ::my_ns
set ::my_ns::var1 100
puts ${$ns}var1     <== wrong
puts $$nsvar1     <== wrong
```

Could you confirm?

Comment: `${$ns}` and `$$ns` do not do what you are trying to do.  Use `[set $ns]` as in Colin's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
% namespace eval my_ns { set var1 100 }
100
% incr ::my_ns::var1
101
% set ns ::my_ns
::my_ns
% puts [set ${ns}::var1]
101
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `$` syntax to do this; this is a syntactic limitation. You have to use something like the single-argument form of `set`:

```
puts [set ${ns}::var1]
```

***BUT*** you have a much better option available to you if you are inside a procedure. The `namespace upvar` command handles this sort of thing nicely:

```
proc printVariable {ns} {
    namespace upvar $ns var1 v
    puts $v
}
```

Also, if you're doing this to simulate an object system, please stop. Use a real object system instead (e.g., TclOO, which ships as a built-in part of Tcl 8.6).